# Angular scope sharing scope from table row to modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-strap

Using Angular.js I have a table of data (using ng-grid) which allows user to click an edit button for any row in order to open an edit dialog (AngularStrap) containing that row's data.  Editing the data in the dialog results in updated values in the grid.

Structurally, is it more common to give the modal its own controller with its own scope or to share the scope of the parent grid's controller?

Comment: You could always create an object in the parent scope and refer to it in your table bindings. `$scope.table = {};`

Comment: Thanks Jim. I am doing something similar where I create a $scope object that contains the object being edited.  The intent of my question, however, is to get feedback on how this type of situation is generally handled.  I have not been using Angular very long and am trying to understand conventions.

Comment: A shared controller seems like a reasonable approach. Depending on the complexity of your application in some cases you could have separate controllers (if the code is getting too complex to read, etc), but then you will have to create a shared service that allows you to use/edit the model in both controllers. In your case that might be overkill. If you are worried about reducing the HTML complexity then use `ng-include` to put the modal part in a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add many models  for the same controller, if all these models used by the same DOMs that located under the scope of that controller. but ideally every model should have its controller for more readable code .